# Why is my thread count going up with rxjava retry error?

Tags: rx-java2

In the function method, I throw a nullPointerException and print out thread count (sout(Thread.activeCount). It appears that each time I retry on error, that the threadCount increases by 1. Why is this happening? Should I assume it will just get garbage collected?

```
public void start(int time) {
    Observable.interval(time, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .doOnNext(t -> function())
            .doOnError(System.out::println)
            .retry()
            .subscribe();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `computation` `Scheduler` used by that `interval` overload is limited to the number of CPUs (`Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`) by default. As you keep resubscribing due to retry, the `Scheduler` will spin up more and more worker threads. However, the total thread count should not grow endlessly.

If you don't want to have so many worker threads, consider using `Schedulers.single()` or `Schedulers.io()` which latter reuses workers:

```java
Observable.interval(time, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.single())
        .doOnNext(t -> function())
        .doOnError(System.out::println)
        .retry()
        .subscribe();
```

or

```java
Observable.interval(time, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
        .doOnNext(t -> function())
        .doOnError(System.out::println)
        .retry()
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: This seems to have made a big difference! I decided to go Schedulers.newThread(),  and surprisingly the thread count did not rise. do you know why that did not happen? I would expect that it would retry on new thread each time, but I appear to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Observable.interval() takes new thread from its computational scheduler thread pool every time you retry. Maybe it does so because previous thread is still in use at that point? IMHO it should not rise indefinitely, as it would indicate some bug.